# My question has disappeared without a trace - what happened?

Tags: support, questions

On August 28, I posted a question titled *A continuous website URL rechecker for Linux?*:

[image: screenshot of posted question]

I am unable to find any trace of this question on the site, not even in my own user's activity.

How is this possible?  Could it be that I left the question as a draft and never actually posted it? Could it be that someone deleted it? What else might explain this situation?

Answer (score 3):

The community user (robot) removed it on Sep 8 at 3:00.   I had closed it as off-topic on August 29th.   Closed questions with little or no activity get automatically deleted in a few weeks.

The link to it was here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108990/a-continuous-website-url-rechecker-for-linux

Moderators and high rep users with permissions to see deleted content can view it and double check the timeline.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm puzzled why users aren't being notified of their own content being deleted.

Comment: Ny the way, this means I won't be getting an answer to my question simply because *Software Recommendations* isn't frequented by the people who know the answer, but that is a more general StackExchange issue without an easy solution, as far as I can see.

Comment: That is correct.   I brought up allowing recommendation questions  here again, but there is little appetite for it: [Product recommendations and offsite resource questions, could they be made be on-topic again?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/product-recommendations-and-offsite-resource-questions-could-they-be-made-be-on)

Comment: @reinierpost `Community♦` deletes thousands of questions across all stacks per a day! its so busy deleting and bumping that it has no time to notify every user :P

Comment: But the software should do that ...

Comment: @reinierpost You should have received a notification that the question had been _closed_ (20 minutes after you posted the question) - since a _comment_ is always made on the question at this time (at least it should be). It is at this time that any action should be taken, since no answers can be submitted until it is reopened.

Comment: @MrWhite: Thanks, that is helpful. But there is no trace of any of that now.

Comment: Should be noted... that this meta has little to no influence how the Stack Exchange platform and features operates.